# Django - javascript path

Tags: django

sometime simplest things are so complex!

I have some javascript which works fine.  I decided to put it in a seperate javascript file that I want to link to my template.
I have put it in folder scripts/a_ajax.js  off the root of the application.
Whatever folder structure I've tried has not worked.
I've also read something about that I must put a reference in urlpatterns but I'm not sure what I had to do.

Can anyone help tell me what I have to do to embed this code as a file?

thx

Answer (score 1):

If your Django version is 1.3+: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

If your Django version 1.2.* or lower: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: wow - this is complex logic - I'm having a hard time following it from documentations - I'm using ver 1.3
I've put my javascript file in /static - 1) I added django.contrib.staticfiles in INSTALLED_APPS - I've updated STATICFILES_DIRS =  ... /static  - based on myunderstanding of instructions I should be done - but I get the following error:
You're using the staticfiles app without having set the required STATIC_URL setting - 

An example would be helpful for this section -

Comment: I have learned google app engine has a different method by updating app.yaml file which is much simpler than the native method offered by Django.  I have used extensions /js/jquery.js - GAE maps /js/  to specific directory for static files.